# Use a cursorloader from another activity

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

Is it possible to make use of - have access to a cursorloader that is implemented from another activity? That is to have a helper class that 
makes all the calls to a cursorloader, and this cursorloader being accessed from different activities. If so, how this can be done? I know that in order for this to work every activity should implement its own cursorloader.

Comment: Loaders are not "connected" to Activities but rather to LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks, so all you need is to implement that interface

Comment: @pskink Sure, but that does not answer the question: to access an activity that implements the interface from another that does not

Comment: you cannot access the "other activity": just create a class that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks and use it wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

As `pskink` pointed out: "create a class that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks and use it wherever you want". Thanks!